# wrong location of displaying image in org mode

Tags: org-mode, images

After running C-c C-c with ob-plantuml, I got this wrong location of image.

[image: picture],

The correct location (as usual) should be,

[image: correct location]

Comment: quick suggestion.. the '...' after #+results suggest that results is folded. try <tab> on that line?

Comment: If you reload your org-mode file, does the issue correct itself? Also what is your emacs version and your org-mode version? Thanks!